# Example: outer measure is sub-additive but not countable additive

Tags: measure-theory

I am looking for an explicit example, but cannot find one. Any help would be great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For a rather extreme example see [Is there a maximum to the amount of disjoint non-measurable subsets of the unit interval with full outer measure?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/is-there-a-maximum-to-the-amount-of-disjoint-non-measurable-subsets-of-the-unit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nonmeasurable sets give examples. One is "the" Vitali set, which contains exactly one element of each equivalence class of elements of $[0,1]$ by the relation "$x$ is related to $y$ if and only if $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$". Denoting this by $V$, there are countably many disjoint translates of $V$, namely $V+q$ where $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,1]$. The union of these is some set $U$, and $[0,1] \subseteq U \subseteq [-1,2]$. So $m^*(U) \in [1,3]$. But the outer measures of each of the translates are the same; thus the sum of the outer measures of the translates is not $m^*(U)$ but rather $+\infty$.

Comment: I understand the example. But how does non measurability show subadditivity? Shouldn't I have a countable number of measurable sets, the sum of whose individual measures exceeds the measure of the countable union, to show subadditivity?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan And you do, that's what I pointed out in the last two sentences. More explicitly, $m^* \left ( \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,1]} V+q \right )$ is some number between $1$ and $3$ while $\sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,1]} m^*(V+q)$ is $+\infty$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan You may miss an important detail: the domain of the outer measure is the entire power set. The outer measure is indeed countably additive when restricted to the measurable sets. Thus *any* counterexample must involve a bunch of nonmeasurable sets.

Comment: Thanks! But the Wikipedia article on Vitali sets says that we cannot assign a measure to a Vitali set at all. Are you saying that we can indeed assign an outer measure to it, although we can't explicitly determine it?

Comment: Yes (this is a part of my comment from a moment ago).

Comment: What if the outer measure of a Vitali set is 0? If we cannot explicitly determine the outer measure of a Vitali set, how can we be sure it is not zero?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan It cannot be zero. I can give two proofs. First: any set with outer measure zero is Lebesgue measurable. (More generally, the measure produced by the Caratheodory construction is always complete.) This can be seen using the monotonicity of the outer measure. Second: $m^*(U) \geq 1$ because $[0,1] \subseteq U$. Thus if $m^*(V)$ were zero then there would be a contradiction (we would be able to conclude $1 \leq 0$). Similarly $m^*(V)$ cannot be any larger than $1$, since $V \subset [0,1]$.